# How to load ajax result in select options as autocomplete?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating an app for places search using Google Places API.

**My Component**

```
<v-select
 label="Type your Address"
 autocomplete
 :async-loading="loading"
 cache-items
 :items="items"
 :search-input.sync="search"
 v-model="seachPlacesModel"
></v-select>

// Script

data () {
 return {
  searchPlacesModel: '',
  loading: false,
  items: [],
  search: null
 }
},
watch: {
 search (val) {
  val && this.searchPlaces(val)
 }
},
methods: {
 searchPlaces (input) {
  this.loading = true
 this.$http.post(googlePlaces + '?input=' + input + '&types=geocode&country=uk&key=' + googleKey + '')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.body.predictions)
    this.items = response.body.predictions
    console.log(this.items)
  }, error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
 }
```

What's working now?

Google Places returns an array on keyup. I can see the result in console.

What's not working?

When I mutate the result in `this.items`, it gives me this error.

`void using observed data object as vnode data: ...... Always create fresh vnode data objects in each render!`

Answer (score 1):

try use unmutable state.
v-select watches for your array.
your should save link to this.items.

```
this.items = response.body.predictions
```

code above replaces link to your array

```
this.items.push(response.body.predictions)
```

If you want add result

```
this.items.splice(0, this.items.length)
```

if you want to clear

you should  in cycle replace unused value, preserving current link to array